# Leibniz determinant formula - Group Theoretic generalization.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, group-theory, permutations

This question rose from pure curiosity (in accordance with my current research).

Given a matrix $A=(a_{i,j})$ of size $n\times n$ we have the butiful way to calculate its determinant by summing over all permutations:
$$\det(A)=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i\in\{1,\dots,n\}}{a_{i,\sigma(i)}}$$

Now, it is well known that $\det(A) \neq 0$ iff $A$ is non singular.

The object of interest is the following;
given a subset of $S_n$ namely; $R\subseteq S_n$, define the $R-\text{determinant}$ of $A$ to be:
$$\mathcal{D}_R(A)=\sum_{\sigma \in R}\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i\in\{1,\dots,n\}}{a_{i,\sigma(i)}}$$

The case of interest is when $R$ is a subgroup of $S_n$, denote $G\leq S_n$

Now, what can be said about the following questions:

- Given $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ what conditions on $G$ and $A$ will imply $\mathcal{D}_G(A)=0$ if $A$ is singular?
- Given $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ what conditions on $G$ and $A$ will imply $A$ is singular if $\mathcal{D}_G(A)=0$ ?
- Given $G$, let $A$ be a bernulli matix with each entry iid $a_{i,j} \sim Ber(1/2)$ what is $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{D}_G(A) = 0)$?
- Given $G$, let $A$ be a bernulli matix with each entry iid $a_{i,j} \sim Uniform(\mathbb{F}_p)$ what is $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{D}_G(A) = 0)$?

Any interesting remarks on this function would interest me.

One thing which follows easily from the definition is that if ${G_1,\dots, G_k}$ are all the different cosets of $G$ in $S_n$ then if $A$ is nonsingular there exists $l\in{1,\dots, k}$ such that $\mathcal{D}_{G_l}(A) \neq 0$. This gives some immediate bounds on my second question.

Comment: Regarding the first question, do you know of any situation in which any $G$ not equal to some $S_n$ will work?

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer I fixed the way it is phrased, the one-directional implication is also of interest.
For instance, for diagonal matrices, the cyclic group is enough.

Comment: I believe that we have 
$$
\mathcal D_R(AB) = \mathcal D_R(A)\mathcal D_R(B).
$$
It would follow that if $\mathcal D_R(A) = 0$, then $A$ is singular. The converse doesn't hold in general; I'm not sure if there any proper subgroups $G$ of $S_n$ for which the statement does hold

Comment: @BenGrossmann the implication is not correct, for instance, take a permutation matrix which is not $I$, and take a subgroup not containing the corresponding permutation. The resulting sum is 0, however, the matrix is invertible (Credit to Gil Alon for the example)

Comment: @Alon Ah, so that doesn't work then. We do have $\mathcal D_R(A^T) = \mathcal D_R(A)$, but I don't know if that's particularly helpful